# IE8: checkbox onclick not called when setting class to that

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have a code like this

```
<input type='checkbox' class='rating'  id="sample"    onclick='checkboxcheck(parameters)'  />
                    <label for="sample"></label>
```

And CSS:

```
.rating {
    display:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url('../images/white_small.png') ;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:hover {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url('../images/golden_small.png') ;

}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url('../images/golden_small.png') ;
}
```

If I remove the class attribute from checkbox tag, my JS function called.
I just want to call the function without remove the class attribute.
I got one solution from SO, which is just change the doctype to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Please provide me the correct method to overcome.

Comment: Is it intentional that you mix `'` and `"` for your HTML attributes? You should choose one and stick to that.

Comment: By the way how do you expect a click handler to fire for an element that is hidden (`display: none`)? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @bazmegakapa , ok I tried to change all the quotes

Comment: @bažmegakapa, no but it is called in other browsers. By the way It is for some rating purpose. If I check one checkbox, a new image will override the old

Comment: I guess I understand now. What about simply putting the handler on the label element? Or using onchange for the checkbox?

Comment: @bažmegakapa , I tried the onchange event instead of onclick but its also not working...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28730/discussion-between-sridhar-and-bazmegakapa)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest modifying your approach?

Instead of `display:none;` you could wrap your checkbox with a div and use it to show or hide your checkbox. I suspect you'll want to keep it hidden all the time though.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hideRating">
     <input type="checkbox" class="rating" id="sample" onclick="checkboxcheck('parameters')" />
</div>
<label for="sample"></label>
```

**Additional CSS:**

```
.hideRating {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.showRating {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  overflow:visible;
}
```

*replaces display:none; declaration in your code*

Let me know if you need an example of a JS/jQuery function to update the class of a `<div />` element.